# AWS Cloud9 IDE "localhost refused to connect." while accessing docker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, localhost, cloud9-ide, aws-cloud9

In the Step 3 mentioned on https://github.com/stacksimplify/docker-fundamentals/tree/master/03-Pull-from-DockerHub-and-Run-Docker-Images ,
to run http://localhost/hello is throwing error ,
as http is not supported by cloud9 localhost (Reference : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-app-preview-http ).

After updating local host port in the command to 443 ; https://localhost/hello getting error : "localhost refused to connect." Already added inbound rule for port 443 at VPC, Subnet and EC2 instance level.

```
docker run --name app1 -p 443:8080 -d stacksimplify/dockerintro-springboot-helloworld-rest-api:1.0.0-RELEASE
```

*It appears that image is not compatible to run over HTTPS:
OpenSSL: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
Unable to establish SSL connection*

**Still, please share if you've any pointers to connect localhost on AWS Cloud9 IDE?**

Comment: The instructions tell you to use port 80. Why do you change to 443?

Comment: @Marcin as http is not supported on AWS Cloud9 .